# std::multiset comparer does not compile

Tags: c++, c++20

Why the code below does not compile?

```
#include <set>

struct FatKey   { int x; int data[1000]; };
struct LightKey { int x; };

struct Compare
{
    bool operator() (const FatKey& fk, const LightKey& lk) const { return fk.x < lk.x; }
    bool operator() (const LightKey& lk, const FatKey& fk) const { return lk.x < fk.x; }
    bool operator() (const FatKey& fk1, const FatKey& fk2) const { return fk1.x < fk2.x; }
};

int main()
{  
    // transparent comparison demo
    std::multiset<FatKey, Compare> example2 = { {1, {} }, {2, {} }, {3, {} }, {4, {} } };

    LightKey lk = {2};
    auto search2 = example2.find(lk);
    if (search2 != example2.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found " << search2->x << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the comparer?

It compiles if I replace the comparer with

```
bool operator<(const FatKey& fk, const LightKey& lk) { return fk.x < lk.x; }
bool operator<(const LightKey& lk, const FatKey& fk) { return lk.x < fk.x; }
bool operator<(const FatKey& fk1, const FatKey& fk2) { return fk1.x < fk2.x; }
```

and define multiset as

```
std::multiset<FatKey, std::less<>>
```

what is the difference?

Comment: `example2` has `FatKey ` as key and not `LightKey `

Comment: @marcinj Why should it be `LightKey`? (since C++14)

Comment: I understand now your question, its from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find. I suppose this is how templated find version (since c++14) is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the overloads of [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find) which take an equivalent type and you are using a custom comparator class that class must have a `is_transparent` member type:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct FatKey   { int x; int data[1000]; };
struct LightKey { int x; };

struct Compare
{
    bool operator() (const FatKey& fk, const LightKey& lk) const { return fk.x < lk.x; }
    bool operator() (const LightKey& lk, const FatKey& fk) const { return lk.x < fk.x; }
    bool operator() (const FatKey& fk1, const FatKey& fk2) const { return fk1.x < fk2.x; }
    using is_transparent = void;
};

int main()
{  
    // transparent comparison demo
    std::multiset<FatKey, Compare> example2 = { {1, {} }, {2, {} }, {3, {} }, {4, {} } };

    LightKey lk = {2};
    auto search2 = example2.find(lk);
    if (search2 != example2.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found " << search2->x << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```